# How to defer LayoutProcessor plugin?

Tags: magento2

I have a custom LayoutProcessor plugin to add custom field in the checkout page.
But the custom field has a dependency from the model.

My problem is the model takes time to generate the value needed by the custom field in the LayoutProcessor (like 10 to 30 seconds) but the LayoutProcessor is already rendered on initial load.  How I can defer the rendering of the custom field so that I can pass the data from the model before it actually loads?

Any help is appreciated.

EDIT: Tried using `beforeProcess`, `afterProcess` and `aroundProcess` but still it doesn't work.